# Undefined reference, but objdump shows the function is in the object file?

Tags: c++, c, linker

Basically, I'm compiling separately a few C files with `g++ -c -o one.o one.c` and then trying to link them with `g++ -o one.exe one.o two.o three.o`.  The linker complains about undefined references to functions called by one.c and declared in two.c.  But if I do `objdump -d two.o` the functions are there, so I'm confused why the linker can't find them?

e: And if I give the linker option `-y <symbol>`, it prints the object file that defines the symbol.

Setup to reproduce:

one.cpp:

```
#include "two/two.h"
int main(void) {
    two();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: one

one: one.o two.o
    g++ -o one.exe one.o two/two.o

one.o:
    g++ -c -o one.o one.cpp

two.o:
    $(MAKE) -C two
```

two/two.h:

```
void two(void);
```

two/two.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "two.h"
void two(void) { printf("Two\n"); }
```

two/Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -c -o two.o two.c
```

Comment: Is it C or C++.  Also, show some sample code.  Perhaps the declaration of your function differs from your definition of your function.

Comment: Mix of C and C++, would that matter?  I'll try to post some code, but the declaration definitely matches the definition.

Comment: Yes, actually. The differences between C and C++ in [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), for example, can give you this sort of grief. So yeah, kinda important.

Comment: Ughhhhh that was it @user4581301 - had to change gcc to g++ in the subdirectory's Makefile.  That's all it was.  Will post answer with small example in a sec.

Comment: Glad it was a quick one.

Answer (score 3):

What I did to fix was just change two/Makefile to use g++ instead of gcc:

two/Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -c -o two.o two.c
```

Comment: You can use the variables $(CC) and $(CXX) to stay out of troubles. Also read about 'extern "C"' if you mix languages

Comment: @fuz - this appears to *be* an answer: "*What I did to fix was...*"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a shared object library, that is there were references in the `.so` that were visible with `objdump` but `gcc` still reported undefined references. What solved it for me was to put the `-l` option *after* the `.o` files that referenced the symbols in that shared object library in `gcc` command line.

See the **OPTIONS** section of https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld for more info.

Comment: What shared library do you mean? The question doesn't mention one, so it doesn't look like the same issue. Could you please explain a bit more what problem, related to the question, you encountered and how -l option solved it?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk It may not be the same issue, but the question implies a more general case then. For me, I was getting undefined reference errors in the linking step when running gcc but when doing an objdump on the library I was linking with -l option with gcc it showed the symbols were there (hence "same issue" as title of this question). For me it was just the command line ordering as discussed in my answer that allowed the symbols to be resolved.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk I do see what you mean though; he doesn't mention shared object libraries specifically; however, `.so` files are subsets of "object files". Edited to say "similar issue" and some clarification.

Comment: Yes, `.so` files are object files, but `.o` files in the question are not libraries and should not be linked using `-l`. Anyway, your related case is also important and it's explained better after your edit, so I upvoted :)

Comment: @YurkoFlisk thanks; eventually I'll be able to vote to if I keep this up :-D. (No rep)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same thing happening.
Doing in the header (.h) file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Your code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Solved my problem.